# No reproduce sonido mp3 en HTML

Tags: html, audio, mp3

Intento integrar un audio en un documento HTML pero no lo reproduce.

**Código:**

```
<td height="380" colspan="3" valign="middle" class="bb">
  <audio src="noticias/entrevista_radio_14feb2017.mp3"></audio>
</td>
```

El archivo se llama como el nombre indica y lo tengo dentro de la carpeta "noticias".

Comment: Hola, has probado con la siguiente sintaxis ? ***<audio controls>
  <source src="noticias/entrevista_radio_14feb2017.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>*** y además que tu declaraación de documento sea html5?

Comment: ¿Cómo haces para que empiece a reproducirse el sonido? ¿Usas JS? Si quieres que suene nada más cargarse debes usar el atributo `autoplay` que no está presente (pero no es recomendado porque puede dar una mala experiencia de usuario).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pones un `audio` en tu página web, éste no comienza automáticamente. Para que empiece a sonar el audio puedes usar el atributo `autoplay`:

```
<td height="380" colspan="3" valign="middle" class="bb">
  <audio src="noticias/entrevista_radio_14feb2017.mp3" autoplay></audio>
</td>
```

O puedes usar JavaScript con el método `play` del audio:

```
<td height="380" colspan="3" valign="middle" class="bb">
  <audio src="noticias/entrevista_radio_14feb2017.mp3" id="miAudio"></audio>
</td>

<script>
document.getElementById("miAudio").play();
</script>
```

> Nota: el audio no debería comenzar por sí solo, es algo que no se recomienda porque puede dar una mala experiencia de usuario, y debería evitarse.

---

Si después de usar alguna de esas dos opciones, el audio sigue sin funcionarte, eso puede ocurrir porque el formato del fichero de audio no es el correcto. Puedes ver una lista de los formatos y codecs soportados por `audio` y `video` en [esta página de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Formatos_admitidos_de_audio_y_video_en_html5).

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con este código para que te aparezca un reproductor:

```
<td height="380" colspan="3" valign="middle" class="bb">
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="noticias/entrevista_radio_14feb2017.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Tu navegador no es compatible para reproducir audio.
    </audio>
</td>
```